# Why can I find a relation by tag but not by ID in overpass Turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to get a specific relation in overpass turbo and then do stuff with it.

When I try getting it like [this](https://www.overpass-turbo.eu/?q=LyoKVGhpcyBoYcSGYmVlbiBnxI1lcmF0ZWQgYnkgdGhlIG92xJJwxIlzLXR1cmJvIHdpemFyZC7EgsSdxJ9yaWdpbmFsIHNlxLBjaMSsxIk6CsOiwoDCnGlkPTI3MDQyODYgxLrEmMS3YW5jb27FiMKdCiovCltvdXQ6anPFnF1bdGltZcWlxacyNV07Ci8vIGZldMWCIMSwxYAgxYjCnGLFmMWaxZzFnsSbxKvEv8WBxYPEugp7e8SQb8WbZGVBcsWAOsaGacWZxZtufX0tPi7GjXLFgsaZxYDFt8W5xI_ElMSdciDGmnN1bHRzCigKICDGrXF1xJLEmsSjcnTFu29yOsaDxYnFi8WNxY_FkcWTxZ7GuyBub8aXWyLFiyI9IsWOxZDFkjYiXSjGgWHGpsWAxqhoxqphKcW3xrx3YXnHl8eZx5vHncePx6DHosekx6bGjseqx6zHksaabMSUacWcx7Jkx5rHnMeOx5_HocejxprHpcanxqnIjMe9x73GrXDEt27HhcazxrXGtwrFssSYx5V5xbc-xbfInHNrZcS9cXQ7&c=BMaazFCptM)

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“id=2704286 in briancon”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “briancon” to search in
{{geocodeArea:briancon}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “id=2704286”
  relation["id"="2704286"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I get an empty response. But when I query the same area by a tag, which the relation I want fulfills, like in [this](https://www.overpass-turbo.eu/?q=LyoKVGhpcyBoYcSGYmVlbiBnxI1lcmF0ZWQgYnkgdGhlIG92xJJwxIlzLXR1cmJvIHdpemFyZC7EgsSdxJ9yaWdpbmFsIHNlxLBjaMSsxIk6CsOiwoDCnHJvdcSVPcSEa8S6ZyDEusSYxLdhbmNvbsWIwp0KKi8KW8WMdDpqc8WbXVt0aW1lxaQ6MjVdOwovLyBmZXTFgiDEsMWAIMWIwpxixZfFmcWbxZ3Em8SrxL_FgcWDxLoKe3vEkG_FmmRlQXLFgDrGhGnFmMWabn19LT4uxotyxYLGl8WAxbXFt8SPxJTEnXIgxphzdWx0cwooCiDGsGVsxJRpxZtbIsWLxY1lIj0ixZDFkiJdKMW_YcakxYDGpmjGqGEpxbXHlsW2xbhwxLdudMa7xrLGtMa2xaTEmG9kecW1PsW1x6Nza8a8IHF0Ow&c=BMaazFCptM) query, it's in the response data (among others) how can that be?

```
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“route=hiking in briancon”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “briancon” to search in
{{geocodeArea:briancon}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  relation["route"="hiking"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: `relation["id"="2704286"]` searches for a relation with the tag `id=2704286`. The ID, however, is not the same thing as a tag!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
  relation(2704286)(area.searchArea);
```

instead of

```
  relation["id"="2704286"](area.searchArea);
```

See also: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Query_by_element_id